# Correct syntax for bash grep function?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

I'm trying to set up a function to make certain grep command easier.

```
gr() { grep -r --include=*.\{m,h,xib\} $1 \* ; }
```

The end result should be a recursive grep of all `*.m`, `*.h`, and `*.xib` files, for whatever is specified by the command's argument:

```
$ gr SearchText
```

Can anyone demonstrate the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind; thought I had tried everything I could imagine; turns out I was just over-zealous with escaping special characters from the shell. The syntax I was looking for is:

```
gr() { grep -r --include=*.{m,h,xib} "$1" * ; }
```